# Find text inside class

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to find text inside class. There are several class with the same name. I have tried in various ways figure it out but I dont know what I am doing wrong.
HTML:

```
<td class="cells"> searchingValue </td>
```

C#

```
var createdUser = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("//div[@class='name' and text()='searchingValue']");
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Well your html class is "cells" and you have @class='name' and not @class='cells' https://www.swtestacademy.com/xpath-selenium/

Comment: sorry, I named it like that only for example. Inside my code it is named properly

Comment: @ascrkn : Checkout my answer and if that not the case then please update question with valid HTML?

Comment: Use dev  mode in firefox to test xpaths. Also you have text()='searching but in the tags you have a space before hand. Not sure if this part of the matching problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the syntax for `classname` this is for `xpath`.

Try following `xpath`.

```
var createdUser = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//td[@class='cells' and contains(text(),'searchingValue')]");
```

---

If you want to by pass search parameter in C# you can do like that.

```
var searchvariable="searchingValue"
var createdUser = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath($"//td[@class='cells' and contains(text(),'{searchvariable}')]");
```